# C# Make Assert Print Expression Being Asserted

Tags: c#, macros, code-generation

When `Debug.Assert` fails, it shows a very unhelpful error:
`Assertion failed`

This can be improved to get at least some information about the location of the error, like function name, file, and line number like this:

```
public static void MyAssert(bool expr,
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    string message = $"Assertion failed in {memberName} ({sourceFilePath}:{sourceLineNumber})";
    Debug.Assert(expr, message);
}
```

This helps, but what would be really cool was to be able to see the expression the caller wanted to assert, something like this:

```
public static void MyAssert(bool expr,
    [PreviousCallerArgumentAsString] string argument)  /* wish this worked */
{
    string message = $"Assertion '{argument}' failed";
    Debug.Assert(expr, message);
}
```

I am just transitioning to C# but in C++ this could be done using a macro like this:

```
#define ASSERT(Expr) Debug.Assert(Expr, "Assertion " #Expr " failed.")

ASSERT(1 + 1 == 3);
/* would expand to */
Debug.Assert(1 + 1 == 3, "Assertion 1 + 1 == 3 failed.");
```

In my code, I use asserts pretty liberally and having to retype the expression slows you down a ton.

Is there a way something like this could be achieved in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck! This functionality was [implemented in C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#callerargumentexpression-attribute-diagnostics), using [`[CallerArgumentExpression]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-6.0).

For example:

```
public static class Debug
{
    public static void Assert(bool condition, [CallerArgumentExpression("condition")] string message = null)
    {
        if (!condition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Assert failed! {message}");
        }
    }
}
```

When used with:

```
Debug.Assert(true == false);
```

Prints:

> Assert failed! true == false

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUPgAwAE+xAdAEroJRgCmDAwgPZgAHKABsOyAMpiAblADGHAM4BuChXwBmOoTrEA7DQDeFGia2Fjpo+VM2aAEQ7BUAcwYBBBQrEIAFAjQcNAC8QTQAZhDCXgCUKtamAL4USeRqmvQAbFr2ji4UVjYaOln4ACw0Hl7IvsC8vMI0srwwGFBszXA0ANrckaLIbsjOqJwwCACiAB4CyIoKUM0+AERNLW0LMEvRALo6tJyeEM6BoTCowsLRFiYFtiZQYTQ+AISrre0wV/F3t3eFxABOHwAEiWlW84Wgogwz0MBwURw4CS2cT+NBSNhSCSAA).

Comment: Great response! Thanks. Sadly, Unity Engine does not seem to have implemented C# 10 yet so I will have to make do without it for now.